# Best practices for storing articles' texts in django website

Tags: python, django, django-templates

New to Django here, please bear with me if this question seems silly.

I'm in the process of designing (and afterwards developing) a blog website. I've identified three types of page that I will have on my blog (article, home, misc) each of these having a separate template.

Every new article would have its own text and images. Presumably I'd be using a single .html template to display many article texts.

Do I store the article texts and images in a separate model? If so, do I store the html of the article text (with all its formatting) in plain text and then render it in the view? What's the best way to do this?

Alternatively, I'd create a new template for every article, but this seems redundant.

Comment: Read about `RichTextField`, it achieves what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce). It also provides good editor in your django admin.
Just install it with `pip`:

```
pip install django-tinymce
```

Add it in your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'tinymce',
)
```

Add tinymce.urls to urls.py for your project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]
```

In your code:

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    content = HTMLField()
```

I showed you the brief installation from [documentation](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce)

Comment: tinymce is good! I've also been trying https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote recently which seems quite nice

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go.